# `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` not being called after calling `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Tags: ios, uitableview

I call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` like so in `viewDidAppear`

```
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [self tableView:self.tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];

}
```

This is `didSelectRow`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1f, 1.1f);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
            cell.textLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }];

    }];
}
```

It runs properly, but then when I select a new cell, the first cell selected in the `viewDidAppear` call to `didSelectRow` does not call `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` it stays black and the animation below doesn't run when a new cell is selected. The problem is the first cell selected in the call in `viewDidAppear` stays selected until it is selected again. Seems to be an issue with the indexPath not being passed without touch.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    }];
}
```

Comment: i set it in `viewDidLoad` should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think u need to tell the tableview that u are selected the cell, for the first time after that it come to know that there is a cell is selected, for this u need do something like below,

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
   {
     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
     NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
     UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     if(cell)
     {
        //tell the tableview that first cell is selected so that deselct method is called after selecting the otehr cell
        [self.myTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
        [self performSelectionAnimationFor:cell]; //perfor your selection animation
     }
  }
```

in the above we are simply selecting the cell and after that we are performing the animation part of your code (see the comment).

for simplicity i separated the animation code like below,

```
- (void)performSelectionAnimationFor:(UITableViewCell *)cell
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        //UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.textLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1f, 1.1f);
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
            cell.textLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        }];
    }];
}
```

and deselection animation like below,

```
 - (void)performDeselectionAnimationFor:(UITableViewCell *)cell
 {
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
         cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
         cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
     }];

 }
```

you can cell these method from tableview delegate method like below,

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     [self performSelectionAnimationFor:cell];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
   [self performDeselectionAnimationFor:cell];
}
```

and also u are already configured the cell selection style to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {

    //...cell creation 
    //set this if u are not 
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    return cell;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was what you said, the cell was not seen as selected even though `didSelect` was called. My code is a bit different in that I had to manually call `didSelect` after `selectRowAtIndexPath` instead of just the animation. It's not what I was expecting the problem to be - I thought maybe there was a variable reference getting lost somewhere and that's why `didSelect` wasn't getting the correct indexPath. It works.

Comment: normally you don't  call the delegate methods of tableview, they will be called by tableview as you know, if in that type of situation comes it is better to write your own method to perform the action, it looks better   if some (or other developer) who has to review the code or develop in feature.. :)

Comment: how would a method like that look like?

Comment: for example see the in my answer  i didn't  call the any of the tableview delegate methods, but i just implemented it

Comment: You mean the animation methods?

Comment: just for example, you can say  that, but the actual thing hear is that we are not calling the delegate methods of tableview which is suppose to call from tableview, not by the programmer.

Answer (score 0):

The method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is a `UITableViewDelegate` method. You are not supposed to call it, the system calls it based on user actions.

If you want to select a table view row you should call the table view's `selectRowAtIndexPath` method instead:

```
[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
```

If you do that the table view will select the row correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Selection  option in the Attribute inspector of the UITableView?
Is it single selection or multiple?

The problem is due to the Multiple selection
The problem is due to the Multiple selection

or you can use in the ViewWillApear instead of didSelectRow because it is not a right way to select the row in UITableView

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                       animated:NO 
                 scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

Comment: Use selectRowAtIndexPath instead of didSelectRow

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't give the effect I need because it doesn't call `didSelectRow` the animation does not get called and the cell just appears grey. Yes, technically the cell gets selected.

Comment: Implement both in viewDidAppear For the FirstTime